# After selecting a tag, auto-clear the search field

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

This is minor, but can be a usability gain:

After searching for a tag and selecting one, auto-clear the search field, allowing to quickly search for another.

Comment: No need to include the tag in the title.

Comment: I could imagine the opposite being annoying.  If you want to add low and high specificity tags like jquery and jquery-ui.  I can do something more middle of the road where upon adding a link I select all the text in the search bar, that way your next key press will clear it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've gone ahead with my solution.  When you select an item, the query text will get selected, meaning the next character typed will erase it.  This should be just as fast as clearing it.

Fixed in the next build.

[image]

Comment: Quite frankly, this solution is truly *perfect*

Comment: @Brian Nickel, this is good. Thanks. BTW, how hard would it be to create a custom keyboard layout, where the dash is available in the 'front' rather than needing to navigate to get it, or maybe allow to eaiser insertion of it... somehow...

Comment: @IdanAdar iOS doesn't support custom keyboard layouts (attempts have been rejected) largely having to do with internationalization concerns.  There are input accessory views (the previous/next bar in Safari).  I think this should be its own feature request.