# Unnecessary selection of typed search term

Tags: support, status-bydesign, ios-app

Using the iOS app, edit a question to add a tag. A tag search box is presented to the user. Type in a word to search for a particular tag, for example "windows". Select a suggestion, for example "windows-8". The tag is selected correctly, however, the previously typed search phrase is then left in a selected form, i.e. Highlighted in blue, with selection markers either side. See below:

[image: Selected typed word in tag search box]

Why is the typed search term selected? I admit that this does not disrupt functionality, and as such is not a functional bug, but more of a UI issue. The selection is not what the user would expect, and if they wanted to select it, then they could do so manually.

Hence, I am marking this as a feature request, in so much as can this "feature" of automatic selection be removed?

Comment: This is by design to support the most common case of immediately starting a new tag while still supporting the case where you may want to increase tag specificity.

Comment: @BrianNickel - This gives for a good UX. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the typed search term selected?

To be able to type over it immediately in order to select another tag, without the need to select and delete it by hand.

A nicer solution would be that the text is just deleted. I guess there was a reason they didn't implement that, although that would be the most intuitive to me.

Comment: I would argue that just leaving the text where it was, unselected, would suffice, but now that you have explained the reasoning, all three options seem equally valid. Thx.

Comment: Original request is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220836/235711).  It looks like I went with selection instead of clearing for the case of increasing specificity. (Adding `jquery` then `jquery-ui`.)

Comment: That was my idea  too. Thanks @Brian

Comment: @BrianNickel - That approach, of leaving it in place in lieu of clearance, certainly is more productive, as it avoids having to retype the same "stem" for multiple tags. It was the automatic selection, instead of just leaving it unselected, that I was querying. Having it selected implies that the user would want to perform a copy... Oh, I see... or... clear by a simple overwrite. Yes, leaving it selected means one or two less taps are required, when wanting to enter a new tag. OK, _now_, I understand your reasoning... :-) Many thanks for the clarification.